# Kubernetes: How do I deploy container from saved checkpoint?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am using experimental checkpoint feature to start up my app in the container and save its state.
I do so because tests on the app cannot be run in pararell and startup takes long.
I want to migrate to kubernetes to manage test containers

- Build and start up an app in the container
- Save state
- Spin X instances from saved container
- Run one test on each container

How do I use Kubernetes to do that?
I uses GCP

Answer (score 1):

Container state migration (CRIU) is a feature that Docker has in a experimental state. According to Kubernetes devs (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3949), looks like it is not something Kubernetes will support in the short term. Therefore, you currently cannot migrate pods with checkpoints (i.e. it will need to start again). Not sure if creating a container image of your started application could help, that would depend on how the container image was created.